# django-mptt's MPTTModel inheritance issue

Tags: python, inheritance, django-orm, django-mptt

Met unexpected behaviour with model inheritance.

I launch this code in django shell:

```
import mptt
from django.db import models


class MyTreeQuerySet(mptt.querysets.TreeQuerySet):
    pass

class MyTreeManager(
    models.Manager.from_queryset(MyTreeQuerySet)
):
    pass

class TreeModel(mptt.models.MPTTModel):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'myapp'
    objects = MyTreeManager()

print(type(TreeModel.objects.all()))
```

And got this: `mptt.querysets.TreeQuerySet`.
But waited `MyTreeQuerySet`.

Checked with Django==1.11 and django-mptt==0.9.1

How can i create MPTTModel's ancestor with custom query set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution for myself: we should use `mptt.managers.TreeManager.from_queryset` instead of `dj_models.Manager.from_queryset`.
I suppose it because `MPTTModel.__new__` has some magic with it's managers list patching. I didn't dig in.

```
import mptt
from django.db import models


class MyTreeQuerySet(mptt.querysets.TreeQuerySet):
    pass

class MyTreeManager(
    mptt.managers.TreeManager.from_queryset(MyTreeQuerySet)
):
    pass

class TreeModel(mptt.models.MPTTModel):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'myapp'
    objects = MyTreeManager()

print(type(TreeModel.objects.all()))

# output:
# <class '__main__.MyTreeQuerySet'>
```